# Eslint esbuild.exe Ransomware detected with BitDefender in React project?

Tags: eslint, antivirus

i cant find any information for what's happening to me in a react project with visual studio code. I'm actually learning to code in React and when I create a new project with npm and install the eslint package, if I scan my pc with bitdefender show me that esbuild.exe (from the / of my project) have the Gen:Heur.Ransom.RTH.1, is this a false positive or something? It's driving me insane because you know, its a ransomware.

I tried installing the lastest and previous versions of eslint and always happens but it shows only if I have the project currently in VSC.